# js.cookies.js not setting cookie

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cookies

I downloaded the js.cookie.js library and installed on website but for some reason it's not setting any cookie.  Here's my code:

```
<script src="/Scripts/js.cookie.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($.Cookies.get('modal_shown') == null) {
        $.Cookies.set('modal_shown', 'yes', { expires: 14 });
        $('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open')
    }
});
//$(document).ready(function () { $('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open') });
```

What am I doing wrong?

BTW, this is put in an asp.net 4.0 masterpage.

Comment: You should use `https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie`

Comment: it says "This project was moved to https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie"  Which is why I went to it instead.  They aren't supporting the jquery version anymore

Comment: Anyone??  Need some help please.

Comment: Anyone?  Need help with this!

Comment: I don't think the library you're using is `jQuery` plugin/supported

Comment: Use https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/src/jquery.cookie.js

Comment: Tushar, like I said before ^ when you go to  github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/src/ it TELLS you "This project was moved to github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie".  https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie is no longer supported.  I don't want to use something that's not being supported and is outdated.  Does anyone else have any solutions for me?